# How to enable and disable a DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css, prototypejs

I am using the Prototype JavaScript library and have this div:

```
new Element('div', {id: 'summaryGraph', style: 'width: 100%; height:90px;'});
```

Inside that div, I am showing a graph:

```
 summaryGraph: function (data, bounds) {
          var p = Flotr.draw(
            $('summaryGraph'),
            [data],
            {
            }
        );
        return p;
    }
```

Now my question is, is it possible to disable and enable the div depending on the conditions?

Comment: could you explain what do you mean by disable, for example if button is disabled it can't be clicked, if textbox is disabled it can't be edited, what do you want to achieve with the div

Comment: Thanks for the reply , please see this site (http://www.humblesoftware.com/finance/index) in this the Child chart(down one) is this div , so i want to disable this graph

Comment: That still doesn't really tell us what you mean by "disable."

Answer (score 4):

If you want to "disable" the Graph you have 2 possibilities:

- hide the Graph and show a placeholder (image, text) stating that the Graph is not accessible at the moment
- overlay the Graph with a semi-transparent DIV, which will prevent any interaction with it

Comment: I mean disable means , no operation should happen on the graph even on its slider clicking

Comment: If you overlay it with a semi-transparent DIV nothing can be done within the graph. You just have to place the new DIV exactly on top of the graph, with the same width and height.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'disabling' the graph. But you may want to take a look at `hide()` ([relevant docs](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/hide)) or `show()` ([relevant docs](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/show)).

If your graph should not respond to mouse events, add a disable flag and in the mouse event listener, return false if the flag is set.

Comment: THanks for everyone who tried , i achivied this way (Event.stopObserving(this.containers.summary, 'flotr:select');)    Sorry for posting a 3rd party related API question